# Put functionalities on Hashmaps

Tags: java

I am learning some optimization trick by using the best data structures, I was trying to understand this line of code. The question is taken from here. https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/

So my first attempt has a `O(n^2)` which is bad so I decided to read through the Hashmap solution.

I have a problem with this line of code:

```java
else {
    map.put(target - nums[i], i);
}
```

The way I understand it is we are taking the `target - nums[i],i` like this

```
9 - 2, 0 = 5, 0
9 - 7, 1 = 2, 1
9 - 5, 2 = 4, 2
9 - 11, 3 = -2, 3
```

The entire code is here:

```java
public static int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (map.containsKey(nums[i])) {
            return new int[]{map.get(nums[i]),i};
        } else {
            map.put(target - nums[i],i);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Any help understanding what this line does will be appreciated how does put operate   `map.put(target - nums[i],i);`

Comment: KEY, VALUE. That is all there is to a `Map`. Here the `KEY` is the `int` value `target - nums[i]` and the `VALUE` is `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting the `target - nums[i]` key with the `i` value in the `Map`, you are saying that in order for `nums[i]` to participate in a pair of elements whose sum is `target`, you have to find another element whose value is `target - nums[i]`, or in other words, find an element whose value is a key in the `Map` (i.e. `map.containsKey(nums[i])` is `true`).

Therefore, once you find an `i` such that `map.containsKey(nums[i])` is `true`, you know that `nums[i] + nums[map.get(nums[i])] == target`, so you return the pair of indices `i` and `map.get(nums[i])`.

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation.